# Redirect 443 Traffic of a Particular Incoming IP Address?

Tags: iptables, squid

Currently, my IPtable indiscriminately sends all incoming request to my Squid transparent proxy. However, since I need SSL to work, I need a way to avoid intercepting SSL traffic.

Idea

1. example.com -> IP= 100.100.100.1
2. http access to example.com -> Send to Squid proxy
3. https access to example.com -> Intercept request for 100.100.100.1:443; instead of sending it to Squid proxy, redirect it back to the ip of example.com 100.100.100.1

Is it possible to do this in iptable? Thanks!

**Edit: I'm adding more information about my setup.**

1. End-Client
2. DNS Server
3. Squid Box

Due to specific requirement, I have to send traffic to the Squid transparent proxy using DNS redirection rather than typical router/gateway redirection.

**Interception Method**

- User Requests www.example.com
- DNS server points www.example.com to Squid Server
- Squid server intercepts www.example.com request

**Current IP Table Rules**

- Forward Port 80 to Port 3128 (Squid port)
- Forward Port 443 to Port 3128 (Squid Port)

Apparently, you are using a typical router/gateway to forward traffic to Squid, you can just forward port 80 and ignore 443 because 443 traffic will go directly, bypassing Squid.

Unfortunately, with my current setup, if I don't forward 443, any https connection will simply timeout.

The only solution now is to intercept all 443 request, map the each domain with each unique IP address, and send the request back to the original source IP.

I tried using Rinetd to forward 443 to the original website's IP address. Unfortunately, this method will forward all my 443 traffic to only 1 IP address because it won't differentiate the request IP.

For example, I map 443 to the IP of Gmail.com. When I visit https://gmail.com, it will work fine. However, if I visit https://hotmail.com, it will still send me to the IP of gmail.com

**I need to find a way to map each IP with each domain so when I visit gmail.com, it will forward to the IP of gmail; when I visit hotmail.com, it will forward me to the IP of hotmail.com**

Comment: You might want to share a snippet of your actual rules in place.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "transparent proxy with DNS redirection" -- that's just a proxy.

Comment: It's a proxy. It's a transparent proxy, and I use DNS redirection to direct my traffic to my Squid box. I don't know why you down-voted this question? I've provided extensive information. I also spoke to Amos, one of the lead developers of Squid. He pointed me this possible solution so I need some helps on how to achieve this on iptable/rinetd.

Comment: What magical DNS server are you using that does this?  Is it saving the requests anywhere?

Comment: @Zoredache: It doesn't take much to make any authoritative DNS server do this – just remove the root hints and add a wildcard A record at the root.

Comment: @Zoredache: I run a DNS resolver for my customers. To answer your second concern, I do not believe this is relevant to my question. Not every deployment is your standard corporate/school network.

Comment: The fact that you are unwilling or unable to articulate the logic behind your DNS-redirection scheme suggests that it's an unnecessary requirement.

Comment: Hi Fission, I would be happy to change my configuration right now if you can offer me a configuration that will allow REMOTE clients to use my transparent proxy for SPECIFIC domains. So please tell me a way that I can allow a client in New Zealand to use my Transparent proxy (No setup requirement;) located in USA to intercept only Example1.com, Example2.com, Example3.com, and leaving other connections in-tact and not taking up any bandwidth of my Proxy server. I look forward to hear you answer.

Comment: I just don't believe it's necessary to judge whether someone's deployment is "necessary" or "unnecessary" because every deployment is unique.

Comment: You could use a PAC (Proxy auto-config) file for this. It won't be a transparent proxy, however. I'm "judging" the fact that you're creating a non-standard configuration (essentially abusing DNS) and then wondering why standard things don't work. This is my final comment on the matter.

Comment: Like I mentioned before PAC is not an option because I do not want to to intercept EVERY connection. I don't understand the "abusing DNS" comment because my clients fully understood the technical requirement. I don't see any problem  in using a creative way to solve an unique business problem.

Comment: You don't have to intercept every connection when using a PAC file; you can proxy only for particular domains. I'd take another look at it, as I think it would really fit your requirements well.

Comment: @fission let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/907/discussion-between-nicolo-and-fission)

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is a "transparent SSL proxy", which effectively doesn't exist (for the *forward* case; it could work for SSL accelerators). Let's see why:

1. The client attempts to resolve serverfault.com.
2. Your "fictitious DNS" server returns the address of the Squid box.
3. The client connects to squidbox:443 and attempts to start a TLS session.
4. At this point, certificates need to be exchanged, etc.

   However…how does the Squid box know what site is really being accessed (ie what remote host to connect to)? The client doesn't tell the SSL server what site it's expecting – it relies on the server to know that already! This is part of the security features of SSL.

It's the same problem with iptables – how would it know what host the client *really* wanted? That information is simply not available (because the "fictitious DNS" server has thrown it away).

The only way I know to proxy SSL is via the `CONNECT` method; and for that, you need to specify the Squid box as an *explicit* proxy.

Honestly, the problem is the DNS redirect. I'm baffled about why you can't use iptables to redirect port 80 and leave 443 alone.

Comment: Thanks Fission. Based on what you said, Forward proxy could work with SSL? I can sign my own certificate under transparent mode but the browser obviously throws a SSL warning. Would forward mode also do this?

Comment: To answer your last part about leaving 443 alone, if I do not redirect 443 to my Squid port, all https connection will timeout because my squid traffic comes from DNS redirection instead of a typical internal network. My deployment requirement is special challenge.

Comment: I said that it was impossible. Squid cannot simply guess which site you're really trying to connect to.

Comment: You are right about "how does the host know what the client wanted". I couldn't really figure this out either.

Comment: what aspect are you referring as impossible? the SSL part or the general DNS-Redirection-Squid part? For the latter, it works perfectly fine. DNS redirects the http request to my Squid box, my Squid Box intercepts it, proxy it, and acts as the intermediary between the client and the external web servers. This setup is working 100% in my present deployment. The only thing I need is to "enable" the SSL functionality.

Comment: The DNS-HTTPS-redirection is the impossible part. I can believe that the HTTP part "works", except for the case where the URL contains an IP address instead of a hostname.

Comment: HTTPS Redirect "works" when I use SSL BUMP to sign my own certificate. However, this is not the ideal scenario because of the nasty "warning page" any browser will throw.

Answer (score 1):

You can not redirect the https traffic (443) to any port, using iptables.

Example: eth1 localnet and eth0 internet

**You can do this**:

Redirect http traffic LAN (eth1). In squid.conf must be the rule: http_port 8080 intercept (transparent proxy)

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Open 443 port to localnet and squid.conf must be the rule http_port 3128 (non-transparent proxy)

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 443 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

**You can not do this**:

Redirect https traffic LAN (eth1) to a squid proxy non-transparent-port 3128 (https) (Fake Rule). It does not matter if in squid.conf the rule exists: http_port 3128

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128
```

**Alternatives:**

1. [Squid-in-the-middle SSL Bump](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/SslBump)
2. Use a filtering by DNS instead of Proxy (like [pi-hole](https://pi-hole.net/)). But it's slower than squid and it does not filter the protocol [DNS over HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_over_HTTPS)